# IBM domino design librarys

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I'm newbie in ibm domino design I can't  import some library like
     org.openntf.domino.Document;

Can any one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ,Finally I solved it I need to add this jar 
http://mardou.dyndns.org/Privat/filesilo.nsf/file.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=E1E0D02D904BD32DC1257C7700741EC9

Answer (score 0):

You can download the current version of the Domino API from [OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API/releases/9C6153F16DCD3D5086257E1A002DAF98)